# How I can update attachments and file path?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have created a table where I'm saving attachments(in external folder) and file paths in the table. When I'm trying to update existing attachment with another, it does not work. Please see below "Add file" code and "Update button" code.

```
Private Sub cmAdd_Click()
On Error Resume Next

 Dim strLokacioni As String
 Dim strSQL As String

 strLokacioni = "C:\Users\HSE\Desktop\datas\" & getFileName(Me.path.Value)
 strSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_tracker(path, filename, IncNo, PATS, SAP, First,        Last, IncDate, Description, Location, OshaType, IncType, RootCause,Inspector,    Surfaces, WeatherCon, WorkRelated, IncTime)" & _
 "VALUES ( '" & strLokacioni & "', '" & Me.path.Value & "', '" & Me.txtInc & "', '" & Me.txtPATS & "', '" & Me.txtSAP & "', '" & Me.txtFirst & "', '" &    Me.txtLast & "', '" & Me.txtDate & "', '" & Me.txtDesc & "', '" & Me.cmbLoc & "', '" & Me.cmbOsha & "', '" & Me.cmbType & "', '" & Me.txtCause & "', '" &    Me.cmbInsp & "', '" & Me.cmbSur & "', '" & Me.cmbWcon & "', '" & Me.cmbRelated & "', '" & Me.txtTime & "')"
 CurrentDb.Execute (strSQL)
 MsgBox "Record Added", vbInformation, "Information"


 Dim fso As Object
 Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 fso.CopyFile Me.path.Value, strLokacioni
 Set fso = Nothing

 Me.tbl_tracker_subform.Form.Requery

End Sub
```

' Below is update button code

```
 Private Sub Command88_Click()
 'On Error Resume Next

 Dim strLokacioni As String: strLokacioni = "C:\Users\HSE\Desktop\datas\" &   getFileName(Me.path.Value)
Me.path = strLokacioni

CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tbl_tracker " & _
       " SET IncNo = " & Me.txtInc & _
       ", path = '" & strLokacioni & "'" & _
       ", filename = '" & Me.filename & "'" & _
       ", PATS = '" & Me.txtPATS & "'" & _
       ", SAP = '" & Me.txtSAP & "'" & _
       ", First = '" & Me.txtFirst & "'" & _
       ", Last = '" & Me.txtLast & "'" & _
       ", IncDate = '" & Me.txtDate & "'" & _
       ", Location = '" & Me.cmbLoc & "'" & _
       ", Description = '" & Me.txtDesc & "'" & _
       ", OshaType = '" & Me.cmbOsha & "'" & _
       ", Inctype = '" & Me.cmbType & "'" & _
       ", RootCause = '" & Me.txtCause & "'" & _
       ", Inspector = '" & Me.cmbInsp & "'" & _
       ", Surfaces = '" & Me.cmbSur & "'" & _
       ", WeatherCon = '" & Me.cmbWcon & "'" & _
       ", WorkRelated = '" & Me.cmbRelated & "'" & _
       ", IncTime = '" & Me.txtTime & "'" & _
       " WHERE IncNo = " & Me.txtInc.Tag


 Dim fso As Object
 Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 fso.CopyFile Me.path.Value, strLokacioni
 Set fso = Nothing


       MsgBox "Record Updated", vbInformation, "Information"
       Me.tbl_tracker_subform.Form.Requery

End sub
```

And the the value Me.path.Value at the start of Command88_click is coming from :

```
Public Function getFileName(ByVal strPath As String) As String 
    If Right$(strPath, 1) <> "\" And Len(strPath) > 0 Then 
        getFileName = getFileName(Left$(strPath, Len(strPath) - 1)) + Right$(strPath, 1)
    End If 
End Function 
Private Sub cbdBrowse_Click() 
    On Error Resume Next 
    Dim f As Object
    Set f = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    f.AllowMultiSelect = False 
    f.Show 
    Me.path.Value = f.SelectedItems(1) 
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the value  `Me.path.Value` coming from at the start of Command88_click??

Answer (score 0):

When I use update queries like you have here, I would always use the following syntax.

```
dim db as database
set db = currentDb
db.execute "UPDATE...."
```

would you require the same? Or have I been going about this a long way.

Also, I would have left a comment as this may not be the answer. Unfortunately, I cant due to rep<50